# John 12:28 - "I have glorified it, and I will glorify it again."

Tags: john

In this passage, Jesus speaks to the Father "Father, glorify your name."

The Father responds and says, "I have glorified it, and I will glorify it again."
When did the Father previously glorify his name?

Comment: Best question on the site.

Answer (score 3):

His name was glorified through all the miracles that Jesus had done up to that point:  the wedding at Cana (ch.2); the healing of the paralytic (ch.5); the five loaves, His walking on the sea (ch.6); the healing of the man who had been born blind (ch.9).  But most especially, perhaps, the raising of Lazarus, which had just occurred (11:1-46).

"When had He 'glorified it'?" asks John Chrysostom. "By what had been done before" ([*Homily LXVII on the Gospel of John*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf114.iv.lxix.html)).

Comment: Straightforward and persuasive. +1

Answer (score 3):

Just after saying "The hour has come", Jesus says "Father, glorify your name".

To “glorify” means to confirm the presence of the holiness and power of God in that person.
The other occasions in which God glorified his name were with Jesus’ baptism (Mt 3:13-17) and His transfiguration (Mt 17:1-8).  These testified to Jesus' divinty.

**Matthew 3:13-17 (NASB)**
*The Baptism of Jesus*

13 Then Jesus *arrived from Galilee at the Jordan coming to John, to be baptized by him. 14 But John tried to prevent Him, saying, “I have need to be baptized by You, and do You come to me?” 15 But Jesus answering said to him, “Permit it at this time; for in this way it is fitting for us to fulfill all righteousness.” Then he *permitted Him. 16 After being baptized, **Jesus came up immediately from the water; and behold, the heavens were opened, and [a]he saw the Spirit of God descending as a dove and [b]lighting on Him, 17 and behold, a voice out of the heavens said, “This is [c]My beloved Son, in whom I am well-pleased.”**

**Matthew 17:1-8 (NASB)**
*The Transfiguration*

1 Six days later Jesus *took with Him Peter and [a]James and John his brother, and *led them up on a high mountain by themselves. 2 **And He was transfigured before them; and His face shone like the sun, and His garments became as white as light.** 3 And behold, Moses and Elijah appeared to them, talking with Him. 4 Peter said to Jesus, “Lord, it is good for us to be here; if You wish, I will make three [b]tabernacles here, one for You, and one for Moses, and one for Elijah.” 5 **While he was still speaking, a bright cloud overshadowed them, and behold, a voice out of the cloud said, “This is My beloved Son, with whom I am well-pleased; listen to Him!”** 6 When the disciples heard this, they fell [c]face down to the ground and were terrified. 7 And Jesus came to them and touched them and said, “Get up, and do not be afraid.” 8 And lifting up their eyes, they saw no one except Jesus Himself alone.

Comment: Nice answer. +1